# How to Return a Specific Item from a Struct with a strings.Contains

Tags: go

I'm new to programming and I'm going through examples of different code used with Go. I have a simple two function program that parses an XML sheet and returns searched items:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type document struct {
    Title string `xml:"title"`
    URL   string `xml:"url"`
    Text  string `xml:"abstract"`
    ID    int
}

func LoadDocuments(path string) ([]document, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    dec := xml.NewDecoder(f)
    dump := struct {
        Documents []document `xml:"doc"`
    }{}
    if err := dec.Decode(&dump); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    docs := dump.Documents
    for i := range docs {
        docs[i].ID = i
    }
    return docs, nil
}

func SearchData(docs []document, term string) []document {
    var r []document
    for _, doc := range docs {
        if strings.Contains(doc.Text, term) {
            r = append(r, doc)
        }
    }
    return r
}
```

How do I get the SearchData function to return a doc.URL instance instead of the entire document chunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [selector expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) `doc.URL` to access the `URL` field in the `document` [struct](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types). Collect the `URL` field values in a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) of [strings](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types).  Return the slice of strings.

```golang
func SearchData(docs []document, term string) []string {
    var r []string
    for _, doc := range docs {
        if strings.Contains(doc.Text, term) {
            r = append(r, doc.URL)
        }
    }
    return r
}
```